# get list of items in react using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

this is the data:
[image: firebase snap]

i wanted to know how to read the "food" children data while i am reading the whole tree. so for each Request id i need to print the address, comment food(and its children) etc...
this is what i used to print the items under the Request but i could not reach to each child under the food item.
any suggestions?

```
  componentDidMount(){
const ordersRef = fire.database().ref().child('Requests').orderByKey();


ordersRef.once('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(child =>{
    this.setState({
      orderId: this.state.orderId.concat([child.key]),
      address: this.state.address.concat([child.val().address]),
      comment: this.state.comment.concat([child.val().comment]),
      name: this.state.name.concat([child.val().name]),
      phone: this.state.name.concat([child.val().phone]),
      status: this.state.name.concat([child.val().status]),
      total: this.state.name.concat([child.val().total]),

    });
  })
```

thanks

Comment: You should be able to access it the same way : child.val().food and have access to the food array []

Comment: thanks, it worked and i posted the whole testing app.

Answer (score 0):

yes you were right, i did the full sample code as below and it worked without any fancy formatting:

the fire.js configuration file for firebase:

```
  import firebase from 'firebase'

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "your app key",
    authDomain: "yourprojectid.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://yourprojectid.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "yourprojectid",
    storageBucket: "yourprojectid.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "this id is given by firebase"
  };
  var fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  export default fire;


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import fire from './fire';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orderId:[],
      address:[],
      comment:[],
      food:[],
      name:[],
      phone:[],
      status:[],
      total:[],
      orders:''    
    };
  }
    componentDidMount(){
      const ordersRef = fire.database().ref().child('Requests').orderByKey();


      ordersRef.once('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(child =>{
          this.setState({
            orderId: this.state.orderId.concat([child.key]),
            address: this.state.address.concat([child.val().address]),
            comment: this.state.comment.concat([child.val().comment]),
            name: this.state.name.concat([child.val().name]),
            phone: this.state.phone.concat([child.val().phone]),
            status: this.state.status.concat([child.val().status]),
            total: this.state.total.concat([child.val().total]),
            food: this.state.food.concat([child.val().food]),

          });
        })

      const ordersList = this.state.orderId.map((dataList, index)=>
      <p>
          {dataList}
          <br />
          {this.state.address[index]}, {this.state.comment[index]}, {this.state.name[index]}
          <br />
          <br />
          <b>Foods ordered: </b>
          {this.state.food[index].map((f,index) => (
            <p key={index}>{index+1}-Food name:{f.productName} , 
          Food ID: {f.productId} , Food price:{f.price}</p>

          )
            )}
          <br />
              </p>
    ); 
            this.setState({
              ordersRef: ordersList
          });
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
        <ul>
        <ul>{this.state.ordersRef}</ul>

        </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

Just make sure you have an ID for each

as an index!